# NoUiSlider Was already initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, nouislider

i'm trying to use noUiSlider with angular JS, i have a directive who contains 4 sliders and i want display this directive on 2 pages.
When i change of page i got an error: Error: Slider was already initialized.

I don't have this error if i refresh my page, but that's not that i want :)

I see a "solution" who consist to modify directly the code of noUiSlider.js but i don't want do this

```
                var familyLevel = document.getElementById('family-level');
                var moneyLevel = document.getElementById('money-level');
                var securityLevel = document.getElementById('security-level');
                var hobbiesLevel = document.getElementById('hobbies-level');
                        service.initSliders(scope);
                        if(Number.isInteger(scope.owner))
                        {
                            priorities.getPriorities(scope.owner).then(function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                if(angular.isObject(data)){
                                    angular.forEach(scope.model.priorities, function(value, key){
                                        if(data[key]) scope.model.priorities[key] = data[key];
                                    });
                                    service.initSliderValues(scope);
                                }
                            }).catch(function(error){
                                console.error(error);
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            appAuth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
                                priorities.getPriorities(user.id).then(function(data){
                                    if(angular.isObject(data)){
                                        angular.forEach(scope.model.priorities, function(value, key){
                                            if(data[key]) scope.model.priorities[key] = data[key];
                                        });
                                        service.initSliderValues(scope);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }

                    },
                    initSliderValues: function(scope){

                        familyLevel.noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.family);
                        familyLevel.noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            familyLevel.setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.family = val[hand];
                        });

                        moneyLevel.noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.money);
                        moneyLevel.noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            moneyLevel.setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.money = val[hand];
                        });

                        securityLevel.noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.security);
                        securityLevel.noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            securityLevel.setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.security = val[hand];
                        });

                        hobbiesLevel.noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.hobbies);
                        hobbiesLevel.noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            hobbiesLevel.setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.hobbies = val[hand];
                        });

                    },
                    initSliders: function (scope) {

                            var sliders = $('.slider-range');

                            for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
                                try{
                                    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
                                        start: 2,
                                        step: 1,
                                        connect: 'lower',
                                        range: {
                                            'min': 0,
                                            'max': 5
                                        },
                                        format: {
                                            to: function (value) {
                                                return value;
                                            },
                                            from: function (value) {
                                                return value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, true);
                                }catch(err){
                                    sliders[i].noUiSlider.destroy();
                                    service.initSliders(scope);
                                }

                            }
                           // initSlider=true;

                    }
```

i had modify my code to add destroy in catch, i don't have error but value of slider don't set to my data

Comment: This may be helpful for you, `Sliders always need to be destroyed in 8.0.` from https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/353

Comment: i have already try to add sliders[i].noUiSlider.destroy() before noUiSlider.create(...), but i got an error that say destroy doesn't exist and if i put destroy in error my slider don't set my value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, it's work.

```
sliders[0].noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.family);
                        sliders[0].noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            sliders[0].setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.family = val[hand];
                        });

                        sliders[1].noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.money);
                        sliders[1].noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            sliders[1].setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.money = val[hand];
                        });

                        sliders[2].noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.security);
                        sliders[2].noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            sliders[2].setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.security = val[hand];
                        });

                        sliders[3].noUiSlider.set(scope.model.priorities.hobbies);
                        sliders[3].noUiSlider.on('set', function (val, hand) {
                            sliders[3].setAttribute("data-level", val[hand]);
                            scope.model.priorities.hobbies = val[hand];
                        });
```

If someone want optimize this part ... ;)